# 20 intermediate haskell exercise - Exercise 9

Tags: haskell

I was working on 20 intermediate haskell exercise. And Exercise 9 is:

```
class Misty m where
    banana :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
    unicorn :: a -> m a
```

And the solution offered [here](https://gist.github.com/dmalikov/1493055) is

```
instance Misty ((->) t) where
    banana x y z = (x $ y z) z
    unicorn f _ = f
```

If I replace m with ((->) t) in banana's type signature, I get

```
(a -> (t->b)) -> (t->a) -> (t->b)
```

It seems a binding function for ((->) t). So why does banana needs three arguments? And why the answer is (x $ y z) z?

Thank you for help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key insight is that the signature

```
(a -> (t->b)) -> (t->a) -> (t->b)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(a -> (t->b)) -> (t->a) -> t -> b
```

This means that the binding `banana x y z` binds the following:

```
x :: a -> (t->b)
y :: t -> a
z :: t
```

And therefore:

```
y z :: a
x $ y z :: t -> b
(x $ y z) z :: b
```

Comment: Thx. I see it now. And with z :: t in expression, banana (x :: (a -> m b)) (y :: m a) can produce exactly the right resulting type (m b).